# How to change Sublime Text 2 selected tab color

Tags: editor, text-editor, sublimetext2

I like the Sublime Text 2 default color scheme **Monokai** alot. The only problem is the tab colors, the selected tabs and the rest of the tabs all look the same (almost). How can I change only the selected tab color for this theme.

Comment: I also found the contrast between the selected/non-selected tabs to be pretty low. If you like dark themes, you might consider trying the new Flatland theme. It highlights the current tab in blue. I posted some screenshots on my blog at http://aspirecode.com/flatland-the-best-minimal-theme-for-sublime-text/.

Comment: It's like you read my mind! Thanks for that question - was bothering me a long time already!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to dig pretty deep into theme customization to do that:

Since your theme is Monokai (medium-dark) go to **"Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme"**

From lines **528** to **531** are your answers...

Either you *hack* by changing **tint_modifier** or **layer2.opacity**

OR

You go right at "medium_dark_unselected_tab_bg2.png" and try changing it by "light_unselected_tab_bg2.png" for example.

Either way I recommend you using [Soda Theme](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/)! A really great and easily configurable theme too!

Comment: I tried the first part modifying the **tint_modifier** and **layer2.opacity** but it didn't work. However, directly changing the PNG files worked for me.

Comment: For sublime-text 3, `Default.sublime-theme` is in the following compressed file `Packages/Theme - Default.sublime-package`. Simply open this file in an archive manager to access `Default.sublime-theme`.

Answer (score 82):

This is the best solution I have found:
https://coderwall.com/p/jg4kog

1. Inside of Sublime Text go to Preferences > Browse packages
2. Navigate to the User folder.
3. There you **create a file** called **Default.sublime-theme**
4. Open that file in Sublime Text and copy and paste the following JSON
   object:

.

```
[
   {"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["selected", "file_medium_dark"],"tint_modifier":[255, 255, 255, 80]}
]
```

Comment: Works in Sublime Text 3 as well.

Comment: To clarify, the values that need to be changed to modify the color of the tab are those in "tint_modifier". These are in RGBA (the A being Alpha or opacity) format. Great tip.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; simple and easy to perform.

Comment: Works with the latest Sublime 3 (now out of Beta).

Answer (score 8):

For my Monokai theme I did:

```
vim ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Theme\ -\ Default/Default.sublime-theme +609
```

This brings you to line 609, then change:

```
"fg": [55, 255, 55, 230]
```

Now fg color will be green.

Comment: it's the set (in case line numbers change) .... {"class": "tab_label",
        "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["selected", "file_medium_dark"]}],

Answer (score 5):

To change Selected tab title color, edit :

`Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme` (as said  Romain)

Then search for the comment *Tab Labels* and change the `fg` attributes of the *classes* that contain `selected` from 255, 255, 255 to your new color (255, 0,0 for red).

Answer (score 1):

If you change the color of active tab header - then you will loose the logic of that theme(tab header and body has the same color and looks like single object)

Rather than changing the color of active tab header, the best approach is changing the color of non-active tab header,  just change the `"layer0.texture"` value to white tab header background .png file in Default.sublime-theme:

```
/** Tabs **/
{
    "class": "tab_control",

    "layer0.texture": "Theme - Default/tab_mask_white.png",
    "layer0.inner_margin": [22, 4],
    "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
    "tint_index": 0,        // tint layer 0
    "tint_modifier": [255, 0, 0, 0],

    "layer1.texture": "",
    "layer1.inner_margin": [22, 4],
    "layer1.opacity": 0.0,

    "layer2.inner_margin": [22, 4],

    "content_margin": [24, 8, 23, 4],
    "max_margin_trim": 6,
    "hit_test_level": 0.4
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out what theme you are using (Preferences > Colour scheme ) 
then open the folder by (Preferences > Browse packages > then the theme named folder)
else look in the default folder....

Find the following files, and edit them in paint! As soon as you save it will show in Sublime.

```
tab-active.png
tab-inactive.png
```

I added a light blue stripe to the top, it helps so much........

Answer (score 0):

For Sublime Text 3 users: As of the official Sublime Text official 3.0 update, this has changed just a little bit.

This SO post in addition to some help from [This Sublime Text Forum Post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/highlight-modified-tabs-build-3143/31303/10) led me to add this code snippet to the **"Packages/Theme - Default/Default.sublime-theme"** or to **"Packages/User/Default.sublime-theme"**

```
    {
        "class": "tab_control", 
        "attributes": ["selected"],
        "tint_modifier": [0, 255, 0, 40], //RGBA value - makes my selected tab a deep green
        "layer1.opacity": 1.0,
    },
```

[Here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/themes.html) you can find more details on the Sublime Text 3 documentation site for themes