# How can i change the tab color on sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

i spend a lot of time on google but all i can find is how to change tab color to sublime text 2. most answers says "locate sublime-theme.." but i don't have any file like that (all files are TmTheme), and the options are in xml instead of json.

Comment: you meant the colour of the whole sublime? Preference > Color Scheme, maybe?

Comment: Sorry, i guess I needed to be more specific, i ment open file tab color. I need to change the ACTIVE FILE tab background color, cos it's almost the same color as the inactive, so i lost a lot of file because of hitting ctrl+s on a different file than i needed.

Comment: Found this, might be something similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543393/how-to-change-sublime-text-2-selected-tab-color

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543393/how-to-change-sublime-text-2-selected-tab-color See Ravi's answer.

Answer (score -3):

My recommendation is to use sublime text [package control](https://sublime.wbond.net/)

To install it follow the instruction in the [website](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation)

or go to View > Show Console menu and paste this code

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '7183a2d3e96f11eeadd761d777e62404' + 'e330c659d4bb41d3bdf022e94cab3cd0'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

Then restart sublime text 3 and press Ctrl+P and type install package

Then install a theme like "[Soda](http://buymeasoda.github.io/soda-theme/)" and open your User Settings Preferences file Sublime Text -> Preferences -> Settings - User

Add (or update) your theme entry to be "theme": "Soda Light 3.sublime-theme" or "theme": "Soda Dark 3.sublime-theme"

```
{
    "theme": "Soda Light 3.sublime-theme"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have the package control, i'll try soda.

Comment: I dont see how this answers the question?