# Editing a Project's Tab Colors

Tags: sublimetext3

I work on 3 different repositories at the same time and I want to have a sublime project for each with the same theme except with different tab colors so I can quickly identify which is which.  I am trying to use darkside-contrast from Dayle Color Schemes.

I opened up the darkside-contrast.tmTheme and it is an xml and I tried editing all of the colors but cannot figure out which one controls the tab colors.

I see that there are some settings like sheet_container_control that may be useful, but I am not sure what to do with this or where I can find a full list of parameters in a sublime theme.  Do I edit the tmTheme xml or do I need some sort of JSON file to specify tab color?  Can I use the sublime-project file to specify this for each project?

I would also like to shrink the tab heights.  Any pointers would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For project multitasking, I'd suggest you simply add each project folder on a separate sublime window sidebar and switch between them. This way each indexed project will be a breeze to browse through (CTRL+T or CMD+T on mac) without any unwanted files from other projects.

Related topic if you wish to check (it's not limited to just Monokai theme but also shows how to create your own theme file with the specific setting you wish to tweak): [How to change Sublime Text 2 selected tab color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543393/how-to-change-sublime-text-2-selected-tab-color)

For reduced tab height, you could use [Afterglow's theme small tabs JSON settings](https://github.com/YabataDesign/afterglow-theme#tab-height-size-options) (biggest size is set by default, add a comma at the end of `true` if more settings are listed):

```
{
    "tabs_small": true
}
```

[image]